# @prisma/client no definition for LogLevel after upgrade from 2.10.x to 2.21.x

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

The title essentially outlines the problem.

Is there a @types/ definition import I'm missing?  I don't see any documentation (thus far anyway) that is helpful.

Prior to the update to latest, the following line worked fine:

```
import { PrismaClient, LogLevel } from '@prisma/client';
```

Comment: Have you run `prisma generate`? There is no @types definition, it's all in the client import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `@types/definition` you're missing. `LogLevel` type was removed from Prisma Client.

You will need to add the logging levels on your own in the Prisma Client as follows:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query', 'info', `warn`, `error`],
})
```

For more information on this, we have documentation on [logging](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/logging/).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using the "Prisma.LogDefinition[]" type, which is imported from

```
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const prodLogOptions: Prisma.LogDefinition[] = [
  {emit: "stdout", level: "info"}, 
  {emit: "stdout", level: "error"}
];
```